# Convert tiff to 8bit LZW compression

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I have code that looks like this:

```
var settings = new MagickReadSettings { Density = new Density(200), Compression = CompressionMethod.Group4 };

using (MagickImageCollection tiffPageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
   tiffPageCollection.Read("input.tif", settings);
}
```

That code intentionally converts a color image to black and white and makes a really small file.

I have been tasked with maintaining color but not making the file too big.

I tried converting the compression method to zip but the legacy software that uses this image failed.

I tried converting the compression method to lzw but another third party process failed (presumably the file was too big).

Of interest:

| Compression | File Size |
| --- | --- |
| G4 | 0.15 MB |
| ZIP | 1.1 MB |
| LZW | 2.3 MB |

How can I change my code to use 8 bit with the LZW compression?

I have seen other code samples that are *not* using `MagickReadSettings` so I am not sure how they apply to my code.

I am using old software so I can't use new compression.  I stumbled on [this article](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/tiff-image-compression/) that boiled it down to use zip with 16bit color and lzw with 8bit color.

Comment: Does it have to be .tiff? .png should offer better compression and is fairly well supported. Since you do not seem to care about being lossless you could also consider jpg, that should offer much better compression, and is probably *the* widest supported format.

Comment: If you have the option of using a professional library, try the [free evaluation of LEADTOOLS imaging SDK](https://leadtools.com/downloads). (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). The SDK can load almost any type of image, including countless TIFF variations, and has several methods for changing the color resolution to provide the best quality for your actual needs. For example, there are different [dithering methods](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/l/rasterditheringmethod.html) to use with the ColorResolutionCommand Class before saving, which can be done using almost any image format there is

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, I haven't tested it for this compression, but I know it supports the LZW compression...

Get the CodecInfo first.

```
var imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(x => x.MimeType?.Equals(mimeType) ?? throw new NullReferenceException());
```

Then create EncoderParameters and adjust quality and color depth as needed.

```
    var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(3);
    var compressionParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);
    var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
    var colorDepthParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 8L);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = compressionParam;
    encoderParameters.Param[1] = qualityParam;
    encoderParameters.Param[2] = colorDepthParam;
```

The colorDepthParam is configured as 8 bit here. At this point you could for example write the image to the disk or or a memory stream.

In my case I had the following code to write it to a Memory Stream:

```
using var image = new Bitmap(imageDataAsStream);
using var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(imageStream, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);
```